# Consulta de fechas tipo timestamp en oracle

Tags: oracle-11g, timestamp

Tengo una columna que es de tipo timestamp, y cuando realizo el insert por defecto es sysdate, pero cuando quiero convertir esa columna de timestamp a date me retorna el siguiente error:

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Quiero obtener los registros del día de hoy de la siguiente forma:

```sql
SELECT *
    FROM MI_TABLA
   WHERE TO_DATE (FECHA_CREACION, 'yyyy-mm-dd') =
            TO_DATE (SYSDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error está en la conversión. Prueba este:

```
select campo1, campo2, to_char(FECHA_CREACION, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as FECHA from MI_TABLA where FECHA_CREACION=sysdate;
```